# Advagg with S3fs relative url() references inside of CSS files - broken image URL

Tags: 8, theming, css-js-aggregation

**Background Images Paths are Changed when CSS Aggregation is On**

s3fs module with AdvAgg to store CSS/JS aggregates on the S3 stream wrapper

Without Aggregation (Works well). fetch from domain base url.

```
background-image: url(/themes/THEME/images/test.jpg);
```

Src of the image in CSS, which is pointing to the CNAME for S3

With Aggregation isn't working. Because, my CNAME is different from my DOMAIN name.

```
background-image: url(http://CNAME_DOMAIN/themes/THEME/images/test.jpg);
```

I disabled it all OBSCURE options(admin/config/development/performance/advagg). But No luck.

Everytime, the CSS file content url() fetching from the CNAME url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and it was the absolute path that broke things https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs/issues/3241554

Had a very similar structure:

`background-image: url(/themes/THEME/images/test.jpg);`

Convert this to:

`background-image: url(/../images/test.jpg);`

(Or whatever relative path that makes sense) and it should work (thanks to @cmlara for the pointer!)

Comment: Still, i have same issue.